# The 'stomp' configuration parameter was not found

Tags: motion-planning, moveit, ros-melodic

I am trying to use STOMP Planner by following the [documentation](http://docs.ros.org/en/melodic/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/stomp_planner/stomp_planner_tutorial.html). As per the documentation, I installed the STOMP from the source in ROS Melodic (Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS). Unfortunately, the command `roslaunch panda_moveit_config demo_stomp.launch` is throwing following error:

```
[ERROR] [1684923835.899294129]: The 'stomp' configuration parameter was not found
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  Unable to initialize planning plugin
[move_group-5] process has died [pid 22522, exit code -6, cmd /home/ravi/ws_moveit/devel/lib/moveit_ros_move_group/move_group --debug __name:=move_group __log:=/home/ravi/.ros/log/12f2b1ec-fa1d-11ed-89a8-181deaf411ae/move_group-5.log].
log file: /home/ravi/.ros/log/12f2b1ec-fa1d-11ed-89a8-181deaf411ae/move_group-5*.log
```

Please note that I already have `panda_moveit_config`, as mentioned [here](http://docs.ros.org/en/melodic/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/getting_started/getting_started.html#download-example-code). Furthermore, I can run the `demo.launch` based on the [documentation](http://docs.ros.org/en/melodic/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/quickstart_in_rviz/quickstart_in_rviz_tutorial.html#step-1-launch-the-demo-and-configure-the-plugin), as shown below:

```
roslaunch panda_moveit_config demo.launch rviz_tutorial:=true
```

I assume the STOMP error is due to an installation/configuration issue. Surprisingly I have not touched anything. Moreover, the error appears even when MoveIt is installed from the source.

Below is a screenshot of RViz:
[image]

BTW, I can see `stomp`, `stomp_moveit`, and `stomp_plugins` packages in my workspace as shown below:

```
$ catkin build
...
[build] Found 52 packages in 0.0 seconds.
[build] Package table is up to date.
...
Starting  >>> moveit_core
Finished  <<< moveit_resources                     [ 0.1 seconds ]
Finished  <<< ros_industrial_cmake_boilerplate     [ 0.1 seconds ]
Starting  >>> stomp                                               
Finished  <<< stomp                                [ 0.4 seconds ]
Finished  <<< moveit_core                          [ 0.7 seconds ]
Starting  >>> chomp_motion_planner                                
Starting  >>> moveit_controller_manager_example                   
Starting  >>> moveit_visual_tools                                 
Starting  >>> stomp_moveit                                        
Finished  <<< moveit_kinematics                    [ 0.4 seconds ]
Finished  <<< moveit_ros_robot_interaction         [ 0.3 seconds ]
Starting  >>> moveit_ros_benchmarks                               
Finished  <<< stomp_moveit                         [ 0.3 seconds ]
Starting  >>> stomp_plugins                                       
Finished  <<< moveit_ros_perception                [ 0.8 seconds ]
Finished  <<< stomp_plugins                        [ 0.3 seconds ]
Finished  <<< moveit_ros_move_group                [ 0.6 seconds ]
Finished  <<< moveit                               [ 0.1 seconds ]
...
[build] Summary: All 52 packages succeeded!
```

Any workaround to fix this issue, please?

### Update

I am debugging the issue. So I would like to share the progress below:

1. The error is coming from [stomp_planner.cpp#L756](https://github.com/ros-industrial/stomp_ros/blob/882784c6952e6456c85d0f61686913a33309bcfe/stomp_moveit/src/stomp_planner.cpp#L756)
2. I added the following snippet just above it to see the values:

   ```
   std::string param_value;
   nh.getParam(param, param_value);
   ROS_INFO_STREAM("The '" << param << "' parameter is: " << param_value << " and namespace: "<< nh.getNamespace());
   ```

   It printed the following:

   ```
   [ INFO] [1685011022.181549319]: The 'stomp' parameter is:  and namespace: /move_group/planning_pipelines/stomp
   ```
3. Suprisingly, I can see the param via `rosparam`

   ```
   $ rosparam list | grep stomp
   /move_group/planning_pipelines/stomp/jiggle_fraction
   /move_group/planning_pipelines/stomp/manipulator/group_name
   /move_group/planning_pipelines/stomp/manipulator/optimization/control_cost_weight
   /move_group/planning_pipelines/stomp/manipulator/optimization/initialization_method
   /move_group/planning_pipelines/stomp/manipulator/optimization/max_rollouts
   /move_group/planning_pipelines/stomp/manipulator/optimization/num_iterations
   /move_group/planning_pipelines/stomp/manipulator/optimization/num_iterations_after_valid
   /move_group/planning_pipelines/stomp/manipulator/optimization/num_rollouts
   /move_group/planning_pipelines/stomp/manipulator/optimization/num_timesteps
   /move_group/planning_pipelines/stomp/manipulator/task/cost_functions
   /move_group/planning_pipelines/stomp/manipulator/task/noise_generator
   /move_group/planning_pipelines/stomp/manipulator/task/noisy_filters
   /move_group/planning_pipelines/stomp/manipulator/task/update_filters
   /move_group/planning_pipelines/stomp/panda_arm/group_name
   /move_group/planning_pipelines/stomp/panda_arm/optimization/control_cost_weight
   /move_group/planning_pipelines/stomp/panda_arm/optimization/initialization_method
   /move_group/planning_pipelines/stomp/panda_arm/optimization/max_rollouts
   /move_group/planning_pipelines/stomp/panda_arm/optimization/num_iterations
   /move_group/planning_pipelines/stomp/panda_arm/optimization/num_iterations_after_valid
   /move_group/planning_pipelines/stomp/panda_arm/optimization/num_rollouts
   /move_group/planning_pipelines/stomp/panda_arm/optimization/num_timesteps
   /move_group/planning_pipelines/stomp/panda_arm/task/cost_functions
   /move_group/planning_pipelines/stomp/panda_arm/task/noise_generator
   /move_group/planning_pipelines/stomp/panda_arm/task/noisy_filters
   /move_group/planning_pipelines/stomp/panda_arm/task/update_filters
   /move_group/planning_pipelines/stomp/planning_plugin
   /move_group/planning_pipelines/stomp/request_adapters
   /move_group/planning_pipelines/stomp/start_state_max_bounds_error
   ```
4. Moreover, this param is not empty and contains long values as shown below

   ```
   $ rosparam get /move_group/planning_pipelines/stomp | wc -l
   115
   ```
5. The similar question has was asked [here](https://github.com/ros-planning/panda_moveit_config/issues/131) but no response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the workaround suggested at [ros-planning/panda_moveit_config/issues/131](https://github.com/ros-planning/panda_moveit_config/issues/131#issuecomment-1582362937), I submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/ros-planning/panda_moveit_config/pull/137). Basically, the following two files need to be modified, as shown below:

1. panda_moveit_config/config/stomp_planning.yaml

```
stomp/panda_arm:
  group_name: panda_arm
  optimization:
    num_timesteps: 60
    num_iterations: 40
    num_iterations_after_valid: 0
    num_rollouts: 30
    max_rollouts: 30
    initialization_method: 1 #[1 : LINEAR_INTERPOLATION, 2 : CUBIC_POLYNOMIAL, 3 : MININUM_CONTROL_COST]
    control_cost_weight: 0.0
  task:
    noise_generator:
      - class: stomp_moveit/NormalDistributionSampling
        stddev: [0.05, 0.8, 1.0, 0.8, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4]
    cost_functions:
      - class: stomp_moveit/CollisionCheck
        collision_penalty: 1.0
        cost_weight: 1.0
        kernel_window_percentage: 0.2
        longest_valid_joint_move: 0.05
    noisy_filters:
      - class: stomp_moveit/JointLimits
        lock_start: True
        lock_goal: True
      - class: stomp_moveit/MultiTrajectoryVisualization
        line_width: 0.02
        rgb: [255, 255, 0]
        marker_array_topic: stomp_trajectories
        marker_namespace: noisy
    update_filters:
      - class: stomp_moveit/PolynomialSmoother
        poly_order: 6
      - class: stomp_moveit/TrajectoryVisualization
        line_width: 0.05
        rgb: [0, 191, 255]
        error_rgb: [255, 0, 0]
        publish_intermediate: True
        marker_topic: stomp_trajectory
        marker_namespace: optimized
```

2. panda_moveit_config/launch/stomp_planning_pipeline.launch.xml

```
<launch>
  <!-- Stomp Plugin for MoveIt! -->
  <arg name="planning_plugin" value="stomp_moveit/StompPlannerManager" />

  <arg name="start_state_max_bounds_error" value="0.1" />
  <arg name="jiggle_fraction" value="0.05" />
  <!-- The request adapters (plugins) used when planning.
       ORDER MATTERS -->
  <arg name="planning_adapters" default="default_planner_request_adapters/AddTimeParameterization
                                       default_planner_request_adapters/FixWorkspaceBounds
                                       default_planner_request_adapters/FixStartStateBounds
                                       default_planner_request_adapters/FixStartStateCollision
                                       default_planner_request_adapters/FixStartStatePathConstraints" />


  <param name="planning_plugin" value="$(arg planning_plugin)" />
<param name="request_adapters" value="$(arg planning_adapters)" />
  <param name="start_state_max_bounds_error" value="$(arg start_state_max_bounds_error)" />
<param name="jiggle_fraction" value="$(arg jiggle_fraction)" />

  <!-- Add MoveGroup capabilities specific to this pipeline -->
  <!-- <param name="capabilities" value="" /> -->
  <rosparam command="load" file="$(find panda_moveit_config)/config/stomp_planning.yaml" />

  <!-- Load parameters for both groups, panda_arm and manipulator -->
  <!-- <group ns="$(arg arm_id)_arm">
  <rosparam command="load" file="$(find panda_moveit_config)/config/stomp_planning.yaml" />
    <param name="group_name" value="$(arg arm_id)_arm" />
</group>
<group ns="manipulator">
  <rosparam command="load" file="$(find panda_moveit_config)/config/stomp_planning.yaml" />
    <param name="group_name" value="manipulator" />
  </group> -->

</launch>
```

Pleae feel free to check the [pull request](https://github.com/ros-planning/panda_moveit_config/pull/137) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the several responses on the ticket upstream I suspect that there's a bug in the configuration that you're trying to launch. https://github.com/ros-planning/panda_moveit_config/issues/131 Most likely there was a change in beahvior over time such that the full name or type of the parameter changed and the config file needs to be adjusted.

I'm writing this as an answer as I don't think that we can effectively provide you with more information that will do more than guess at things that could help you debug. The main thing is to follow up on that ticket and since that ticket hasn't been responded to in a while, you'll likely need to dig into it yourself.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestions. I added the answer [below!](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/a/25056)